# Why does Xcode's unit tests always pass?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

I want to use TDD in Xcode, but every at every run, even a failing

```
- (void)testThatFails {
    XCTAssertTrue(FALSE, @"FAIL");
}
```

will result in a "Test Succeeded" message from Xcode.

Also, I have no feedback from the tests on the console, saying which test were executed, etc...

Anybody has ever experienced the same problem?

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 and iOS 9.1.

Comment: So, I tried a simple `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` in the terminal and it returned a warning about a plugin, saying that a given UUID was missing from the `Info.plist`.

Comment: title should be a brief of your problem not a statement

Comment: I added the missing key and given UUID, but to no avail. I then deleted the faulty plugin. `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` do works fine now, but still the same problem...

Comment: I tried on an iPod with iOS 8.3 on it, and it works fine! Also on another iPhone with iOS 9.1. So it is definitely related to my device...

Comment: Ok, I restarted my iPhone and it is now working fine !

Comment: @KumarSaurabh thank you, I edited the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in one of my comments, from Nov 24 '15 at 7:53

> Ok, I restarted my iPhone and it is now working fine !

Strange but that's the way it is.

Also, I never had the problem again since, and it's been more than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a **"target membership"** problem

your test class should always be targeted to the unit test target like this way:

[image]

otherwise the result is **nothing to test** and green lights ;)

Comment: Thank you for the insight, but it was not the case this time. 
As I said in the comment, it all worked fine after restarting my iPhone.
But I'll keep an eye on the problem you experienced!
++